# how to add comma after a pattern in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a data of say 1000 records
like

```
FULL_TTL
07-26-16 Duane C. Abbey REP Telemedicine 2016: Coding, Billi
02-05-14 David Lim REP CE Marking: MDD, AIMDD, and IVDD
10-08-15 Dr. David Lim REP FDA's Regulation of Human Cells, 
10-20-15 Melanie Witt REP Hysterectomy: Coding, Coverage, an
05-12-16 Jill M. Young REP Guidelines, Tools and References 
07-21-16 Gail Madison-Brown TRE Healthcare Fraud, Waste and
10-21-15 John E. Steiner TRE EMTALA: Practical Tips, Complia
03-03-15 Angela Bazigos  TRE Identification, Correction & Pr
```

in excel,i put a formula in a whole sheet and result comes out to be given below for all records

I want

```
07-26-16, Duane C. Abbey, REP Telemedicine 2016: Coding, Billi
```

Please do the needfull

Comment: Are they in one row or in different columns?

Comment: what was the formula you used?

Comment: @Maki they are in same column means in one column

Comment: "Please do the needfull" - actually, we ask that of you. Please try something, and let us know what did/didn't work. This is not a "code for me" site, as outlined in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're more than happy to help with existing code, point out errors, etc. But we ask the user to make an attempt first.

Comment: i want comma after date and the keyword REP or TRE

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark all sheet (ctr+a)
2. "Use find and replace" (ctrl+h)
3. FIND: " REP " REPLACE WITH: " REP, " click REPLACE ALL
4. FIND: " TRE " REPLACE WITH: " TRE, " click REPLACE ALL

To get comma following the date:

EASY:

1. copy everything to notepad ++ (freeware)
2. use multirow coursor (alt+Lmouse drag vertically in the text column following date) and input ",".

INTERMEDIATE:

1. use regular expressions - replace "../-../-.." with "../-../-../,".